# Is malloc() for user-inputted array is a must?

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

While i was preparing for my finals,i realized that i can create user-inputted arrays without using any dynamic memory functions.

So i was wondering what is the difference then,why should we use malloc instead of just scanf the input? (I know there is an advantage of free() but that doesn't count.)

[image]

I was just expecting an error that refuses me to make an user-inputted array without any dynamic memory allocation functions.

Comment: Please type all relevant code and other information in your question instead of providing references. Otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `scanf` no matter *how* you allocated your array?

Comment: Your question is framed in a subjective light. An objectively framed version of this question can be found here: [*What's the difference between a VLA and dynamic memory allocation via malloc?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31199566/2505965) And some further, more nuanced reading can be found here: [*What's the point of VLA anyway?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22530363/2505965)

Answer (score 1):

With `malloc()` (or `calloc`) you can much easier manage memory usage of your application since, as you said, you can free the memory whenever you want or need.

Other huge advantage is `realloc()` function which allows you to change size of your data/array which is common need in many applications if you don't want to limit the user by some maximal input (or output) size limit.

Other advantage you'll highly decrease the risc of running out of stack memory. Variables created in functions without `static` keyword are saved on the stack which might be easily full by creating a large array. If you use dynamic allocation then the array is saved on the heap.

Comment: there is similar question here with an answer that explains automatic arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698739/why-am-i-not-getting-a-compile-error-when-declaring-a-c-array-with-variable-size